# Why do the BackOffice login page keeps on reloading on my Prestashop website?

Tags: prestashop

I've got a Prestashop installation and when I try to login to the backend it reloads the page. I've tried to edit the following section in Cookie.php

```
    public function isLoggedBack()
    {
        Tools::displayAsDeprecated();
        /* Employee is valid only if it can be load and if cookie password is the same as database one */
        return ($this->id_employee
            && Validate::isUnsignedId($this->id_employee)
            && Employee::checkPassword((int)$this->id_employee, $this->passwd)
//&& (!isset($this->_content['remote_addr']) || $this->_content['remote_addr'] == ip2long(Tools::getRemoteAddr()))
        );
    }
```

I've tried this in different web browsers with no luck.
Is there a proper solution available for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem anytime and it was solved cleaning the browser cookies.

Hope that helps you